# Why drf add underlines to serialized dictfield?

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I use djangorestframework==3.9.4, I can't realize why drf changes serialized data (add underlines to field names before numbers and uppercase)

```python
# views.py:

class RetrieveUpdateJsonFields(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                                mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                                viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = JsonFieldObject.objects.all()

    serializers = {
        'default': JsonFieldRetriveSerializer,
        'update': JsonFieldUpdateSerializer,
    }

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return self.serializers.get(self.action,
                                    self.serializers['default'])
                                    
        
# serializers.py:
                            
class JsonFieldUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    context = serializers.JSONField()

    class Meta:
        model = JsonFieldObject
        fields = ('id', 'context')
        
    def validate(self, data):
        """ for trace """
        print(data["context"])
        return data
```

I try send put request, that contains next data:

```json
{
    "id":1,
    "context": {
        "floor_field": 27,
        "square2": 222,
        "oneAs": "Hello"
    }
}
```

in serializer I expected this:

`{'id': 1, 'context': {'floor_field': 27, 'square2': 222, 'oneAs': 'Hello'}}`

but got:

`{'id': 1, 'context': {'floor_field': 27, 'square_2': 222, 'one_As': 'Hello'}}`

how can I disable this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DRF does this jobs based on Python `PEP8` style guide.

You can disable it with third-party tools. It seems you are expecting `camelCase`. so to get camelCase response, use `djangorestframework-camel-case`:

install it `pip install djangorestframework-camel-case`

Update your DRF setting like this:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # ...
    'JSON_UNDERSCOREIZE': {
        'no_underscore_before_number': True,
    },
    # ...
}
```

If you want more advance configuration, you can follow this:
# ...
REST_FRAMEWORK = {

```
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'djangorestframework_camel_case.render.CamelCaseJSONRenderer',
        'djangorestframework_camel_case.render.CamelCaseBrowsableAPIRenderer',
        # Any other renders
    ),

    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
        # If you use MultiPartFormParser or FormParser, we also have a camel case version
        'djangorestframework_camel_case.parser.CamelCaseFormParser',
        'djangorestframework_camel_case.parser.CamelCaseMultiPartParser',
        'djangorestframework_camel_case.parser.CamelCaseJSONParser',
        # Any other parsers
    ),
}
# ...
```

More details can be found here: https://github.com/vbabiy/djangorestframework-camel-case